# Connecting to MySQL using mono on Solaris

Tags: .net, mysql, mono, solaris

I'm trying to use a MySQL database using mono 2.8.1 on Solaris 10. To do that, I'm trying to use the official [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). But I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Protocol option not supported
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_ReceiveTimeout () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.get_ReadTimeout () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream baseStream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream)
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream baseStream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean compress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Apparently, [Solaris doesn't support `ReceiveTimeout`](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3300082), which the connector (indirectly) uses.

Is there some way to work around this exception? Or another way to use MySQL database from mono on Solaris?

Comment: the link suggests that you try the async commands of the socket, have you tried the async commands in the library to access the db?

Comment: There aren't any commands to access the DB asynchronously in the library.

Comment: Have you tried connecting via the SharedMemory option in the connection string?

Comment: @Handjoerg, wouldn't that work only if the SQL server was on the same machine I'm logged to? That's not the case here. In any case, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Specially for that question I have set up a virtual machine with solaris 10 and followed these instructions: 
Partly: [http://developer.mindtouch.com/User:deprecated/**Archive/SAMP*(Solaris10,Apache2,MySQL5,PHP5)_with_Mono_setup-guide_for_MindTouch](http://developer.mindtouch.com/User%3adeprecated/%2a_Archive/SAMP_%28Solaris10,Apache2,MySQL5,PHP5%29_with_Mono_setup-guide_for_MindTouch)

and http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL

as the last example worked for me.

Comment: Weird, I just tried the example and it didn't work. It failed with the same exception as before. I didn't have to install anything though, everything was already installed on the server (except for the MySQL connector). What version of the connector did you use? Did you compile it?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 ultimate, VMWare 7.1.3 build-324285, SunOS sol10 5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc i386 i86pc. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.2-m5, mono-2.10-sgen-solaris (have reinstalled it from pkg), mysql-5.1.60-solaris10-x86_64 (use the dll from v4 folder).

Comment: Thanks, but the installer you listed (at least in the latest version 5.5.15) doesn't seem to contain the connector DLL.

Comment: Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads, select mono, get the latest zip.

Comment: yeah, that's the same one I used too. I have no idea why it works for you but not me.

Comment: @svick: Have you tried connecting via the SharedMemory option?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but the DevArt MySQL connector ([dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/)) officially supports Mono and perhaps it doesn't have the problems on Solaris (by not using ReceiveTimeout). The DevArt database connectivity components are very reliable, performance is awesome and they are also reasonable priced. Of course you can test your scenario with their trial.

Comment: That would be a very reasonable price if I was being paid for doing this, but I'm not.